# UIScrollView, paging and rotation: Second view is not aligned properly after rotation

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiscrollview

I am using a UIScrollView with Paging enabled and the following code to add subviews (core plot charts) to it.

The horizontal scrolling between the views works properly. 
However, when showing the second view and then **rotating** from landscape to portrait mode, the second view is shifted partly to the right and a portion of the first view's right hand side is shown on the left side, hence "destroying" the paging mode.

Could you **help** me with these issue **please**? I tried many alternatives, but can't find my bug. Thank you so much!

This is how my iPad screen looks after rotating to portrait mode with the second view:

[image: Parts of first screen (large bars) shown on the left side of the second screen]

:

This is my viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(768 * 2, 400);
chart1 = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 400)];
chart2 = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(768, 0, 768, 400)];

self.scrollView.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
chart1.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
chart2.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
self.scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth ;

chart1.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth ;
chart2.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth ;
[self.scrollView addSubview:chart1];
[self.scrollView addSubview:chart2];
```

}

This is how I have implemented rotation:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation

 {
    if  (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(fromInterfaceOrientation)) {
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(704 * 2, 400);
        chart1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 704, 400);
        chart2.frame = CGRectMake(704, 0, 704, 400);
        }
    else {
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(768 * 2, 400);
        chart1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 400);
        chart2.frame = CGRectMake(768, 0, 768, 400);
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should change the contentOffset of the scrollview when rotation is taking place.
You should have a way to know which page is currently displayed before rotation (maybe put this information in a variable). Then in your didRotate.. method set the contentOffset of the scrollview after resizing it, like this:

```
CGFloat offset = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * currentPageIndex;
[self.scrollView setContentOffset: offset];
```

Comment: Could it be that the resizing (decrease of the contentSize), which occurs after rotation is distorting the second view? I believe the second view should be shifted to the left by a certain pixel amount after the rotation. How could I put this rotation in code? Any ideas? Thank you, ale84!

Comment: Have you tried to set the contentOffset in didRotation as I suggested?

Comment: I tried setting the contentOffset to scroll to the beginning of the respective view and it works. However, it seems to me that this is a work around. Isn't there any more elegant version to support paging and rotation?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to laying out your subviews in your view controller, have you considered subclassing your UIScrollView and overriding it's layoutSubviews method? You might also consider defining your dimensions as percentages rather than fixed points - because the point values will shift according to rotation and presence of other UI elements such as navigation and toolbars. You may run into trouble as you're manually resizing UI elements in your rotation method, at the same time that the UI is going to be attempting to automatically resize elements according to your resizing masks. Just my thought...

Comment: Hi Isaac, I do not want to subclass UIScrollView. I believe UIScrollView should offer the behavior I need out of the box.

Comment: When you mix behaviors of views and view controllers, you can sometimes run into hard-to-reconcile layout issues. I understand that you would rather not subclass, and that's fair enough. My suggestion stems from the fact that you are manipulating view layouts in your view controller, which is blending the roles of views and controllers. I don't claim to be immune from the practice, but, if you're looking for an elegant solution, fall back to the tried and true: Let views be views (which includes laying out their own subviews), and let controllers be controllers. Good luck!